# how to show the div using this in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i need

- i just need to show div.

code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" onclick="$(this).show();" style="color:green">view detail
    <div class="speakers dis-non">

    </div>
</a>
```

- when I changed code to `onclick="$('.speakers').show();"` then its working fine.

  problem occurs:

  - `onclick="$(this).show()"`
  - no div is shown.
- i need when user click on particular anchor element then data should of that particular link click should be shown.

Comment: `$(this)` is your anchor tag, not the `div`.

Comment: That doesn't look like a link to me. You're better off using a `<button>` instead of an `<a>`. If you must use an `<a>`, add `role="button"` to override its link semantics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to target element using:

```
$(this).find('div').show();
```

Or to make it more specific with:

```
$(this).find('.speakers').show();
```

Answer (score 3):

`$(this)` refers to the element you click on, in this case the a tag and not the div you want to show.

Try `$(this).children('div').show();`

Answer (score 2):

You have to select first div element using:

```
$('this').children('div').show();
```

Answer (score 2):

This will show the div inside the anchor tag

```
$(this).children(".speakers").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` refers to the clicked anchor instead of the div. Use `$(this).children('div.speakers').show();` to target div with `speakers` class inside the anchor.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" 
    onclick="$(this).children('div.speakers').show();" 
    style="color:green">view detail
    <div class="speakers dis-non">

    </div>
</a>
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fw3sgc21/

Comment: i  have refr yr link and i need when user click it shows div then i want to hide link i have tried but after struggle i need yr help

Comment: in yr js fiddle if click on view detail then i want t show speaker class and hide view detail link i have tried buts it not working

Comment: please answer my link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27289097/click-on-link-to-show-data-on-div-and-link-disappear-is-not-working