# Click on Link to show data on div and Link Disappear is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

What I need

- I need when user click on link data is shown.
- link disappear after click.

I have tried code

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewdetail more" 
    style="color:#8989D3!important;">view details
    <div class="speakers dis-non">
    </div>
</a>
```

jquery code

```
$('.viewdetail').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.speakers').show();
    $(this).find('.viewdetail').hide();
});
```

problem

- when I click on view detail link data is shown on div.
- link doesn't disappear.
- if I put anchor before div then data is not shown on speaker class div.
- any suggestion are most welcome.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fw3sgc21/

Comment: how can you hide parent and show child in it?? this does not make any sense :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the div is inside the anchor, the div will also be hidden if you hide the anchor. You need to put the div next to the anchor to make it work. Use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method to select the div.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" style="color:green">view detail</a>
<div class="speakers dis-non" style="display: none">
    test data to be shown
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#viewdetail').on('click', function(){
    // show div with speakers class next to the anchor
    $(this).next('div.speakers').show(); 

    // hide the anchor
    $(this).hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fw3sgc21/2/

**EDIT**

If you want to wrap the `speakers` div inside another div as below

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" style="color:green">view detail</a>
<div class="12u">
    <div class="speakers dis-non">
        test data to be shown
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
.dis-non
{
    display: none;
}
```

Here's the JS that should show the `speakers` div and hide the clicked anchor

```
$('#viewdetail').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().children('div.speakers').show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fw3sgc21/6/

**EDIT 2**

If you want to put the anchor inside two divs as below

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" style="color:green">view detail</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="12u">
    <div class="speakers dis-non">
        test data to be shown
    </div>
</div>
```

Use [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method twice to select `<div class="a">`, then use `.next().children('div.speakers').show()` to show the `speakers` div

```
$('#viewdetail').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next().children('div.speakers').show();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fw3sgc21/8/

Comment: perfect answer that i was searching for

Comment: in js fiddle when you add extar div class <div class=12u><div class="speakers dis-non" style="display: none">
    test data to be shown
</div></div> then next is function is not able to show the hide div

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$('.viewdetail').click(function()
{
     $('.speakers').show();
     $(this).hide();
});
```

`$(this)` refers to the `.viewdetail` so you don't need the `find` it again

Pull the div outside the hyperlink

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="viewdetail more" style="color:#8989D3!important;">view details</a>

<div class="speakers dis-non"></div>
```

Comment: link disapper but you could check then data in div should also be disapear , i want data should be visible after click on link and want link should disappear

Comment: why do you put this inside your hyperlink `a` tag? Pull the div just after the hyperlink

Comment: dis-non is same as display none im using skell js

Comment: I have removed the css rule

Answer (score 0):

try this

html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="viewdetail" style="color:green">view detail

</a>
    <div class="speakers dis-non">
        test
    </div>
```

js

```
$('#viewdetail').click(function() {
                $('.speakers').show();
                $(this).hide();


            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fw3sgc21/1/

Comment: dis-non is same display none

Comment: fine now ? you have not posted your css code then how can i know

Answer (score 0):

First of all `this` in your code refers to to the clicked link itself.
So this line `$(this).find('.viewdetail').hide();` doesn't work, because there is no `.viewdetail` inside of link. It should be

```
$('.viewdetail').on('click',function(e) {
        var self = $(this);
        self.find('.speakers').show();
        self.hide();
});
```

But, if you hide your link, the `.speakers` will be also hidden, because it's inside of your link. If you want it to be visible, you should place it outside of link

For example:

```
<a href="#" class="viewdetail more" style="color:#8989D3!important;">view details</a>
<div class="speakers dis-non"></div>
```

And JS:

```
$('.viewdetail').on('click',function(e) {
        var self = $(this);
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent link from working the way it should
        self.next('.speakers').show();
        self.hide();
});
```